How do I choose the default Python by its path?
The Windows 8.1 PC I'm working on has several Pythons installed in different locations (as indicated by py -0p). Most of them are to be considered unreliable: their versions are changed, they get deleted, configured and added. One of the Pythons is mine, and I'd like to set its location as the default on the PC without prohibiting access to other Pythons.
At least, I'd like for py to launch Python from the specific location regardless of versions and other Pythons.

Troubles with the tools I've found:

changing PATH doesn't affect the py command
py.ini (as far as I'm aware) only allows version selection and not path selection
the same goes for PY_PYTHON
deleting other Pythons will solve the problem only temporarily (and also be very rude)
shebang doesn't change the default version and may lead to an unreliable Python
venv seems to be clunky: I would like to use python with minimal setup each time

I was asked to provide the results of something like py -0p (the same as py --list-paths). Here they are, but bear in mind, that this list is not stable and is usually changing
Installed Pythons found by py Launcher for Windows                                                                                                      
 -3.9-64        C:\Program Files (x86)\...\Python39_64\python.exe *                                                          
 -3.8-64        C:\Program Files\Python38\python.exe 


Note that Windows 8.1 hit EOL in January of 2023. It's a dead operating system, and giant security vulnerability.

You could write a py.bat or Powershell script that does what you want and set its location as the first in PATH.

py shouldn't be affected by your path. The other things you say don't make much sense and aren't in line with how py is supposed to work. https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher Can you provide more details - what actually happens, what python executables are used, where are they? I'd stick to the use case you want to use rather than worry about all the possibilities (i.e., I want to use this python but I am getting that python when I do such and such). Also fwiw feel free to go ahead and be rude and remove the unreliable (unsupported?) pythons.

You say py.ini only allows version selection, but not path selection. Are you implying that you have multiple copies of the same version of Python installed? That would make some sense in the context of virtual environments, but py is mostly useful for managing access to global environments for Python. You don't want to use virtual environment copies without activating the virtual environment and when you do, you'd use python and not py?

@topsail I've read the docs and just wanted to avoid unhelpful answers. Other Pythons are not unsupported  —  other users of the PC meddle with them (yes) in many ways, and I want to use vanilla Python. Also, I'm not sure if specific file paths would be useful, since they change constantly (except for py.exe's and my Python's)

@Grismar well, yes, that is the case, but the question is more general: I may update my Python in the future, so I was thinking of a reliable solution to my problem.

what is the output of py --list?

I've added an example in the question, @topsail. py --list-paths gives more info, though.

so if py --list-paths gives more info, how about sharing that too? and which of these paths do you want to use?

If you update your Python, that still leaves your system with only one of each version installed, so it doesn't change the premise. If you're looking for a way to ensure a specific version is used for some use case, use virtual environments - it's what they are for. If you're looking for a way to manage available global pythons, Python Launcher already does it all. It doesn't seem like there's an actual question here, other that asking about a hypothetical situation that won't actually occur.

No, Grismar, Launcher doesn't allow for enough control and this question is very much practical. Somebody gave a nice answer about pyenv, but I don't see it anymore.

@topsail, check the last codebox, please. py --list-paths is an alias for py -0p. I'll add this into the question, to avoid further confusion, though; thank you.

Per the docs, "Unlike the PATH variable, the launcher will correctly select the most appropriate version of Python. It will prefer per-user installations over system-wide ones, and orders by language version rather than using the most recently installed version" so it seems like a possible solution is to install python for your user instead of using "system" or "global" pythons (from C:\ProgramFiles...) I'm a little curious about this "meddling" with python that other users are doing - I can't imagine what that would be.
